# Plot a curve in 3D with Sympy

Tags: python, plot, sympy, curve, mplot3d

How to plot the following 3D curve (as an example) using Sympy? I know just create an array for t and do this in Matplotlib, but I don't really want to plot *this* curve, rather to learn how to define and plot curves symbolically.

> alpha(t) = (cos(t), sin(t), t)

```
from sympy import *

t = symbols('t')
alpha = [cos(t), sin(t), t]

# now what?
```

I have tried using the plot method in various ways but this has only resulted in either three separate 1D curves, or an error.

Comment: Study this http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use methods from `sympy.plotting`, in your case your need `plot3d_parametric_line`:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot3d_parametric_line

t = symbols('t')
alpha = [cos(t), sin(t), t]
plot3d_parametric_line(*alpha)
```

or `plot3d_parametric_line(cos(t), sin(t), t, (t, 0, 2*pi))` if you like to set limits of t.

[image]
Look for more examples to plot in 3d with sympy: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/examples/beginner/plot_examples.py

Answer (score 2):

I never tried ploting in sympy

I suspect more will have matplotlib experience

**lambdify()** is the interface between symbolic expressions and regular functions

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
import math

t = symbols('t')
alpha = [cos(t), sin(t), t]

f = lambdify(t, alpha)

T = [2*math.pi/100*n for n in range(100)]
F = [f(x) for x in T]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
ax1.plot(*zip(*F))
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this answer is outdated. This definition of `alpha` leads to an error `AttributeError: 'Zero' object has no attribute 'cos'`. With `alpha = [2*t, 3*t, t]`, the second last line leads to `NotImplementedError: It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect on 3D axes`, which is described [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15382).